# OpenLayers 3 and Geoserver: Create popup on marker click

Tags: javascript, popup, openlayers, openlayers-3, geoserver

I have an OpenLayers 3 map with WMS layers from my Geoserver. I am trying to create a popup window on marker click (from the WMS layer) with the popup's content data from WFS GetFeature method. I have a JsFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/liostse/737tdcz1/4/).

The code is rather simple and based on other SO posts.

```
var baselayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.OSM()
});
var layer1 = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
    url: 'http://88.99.13.199:8080/geoserver/agristats/wms',
    params: {
      'LAYERS': 'agriculture:megaladimosia',
      'STYLES': 'point',
      'TILED': true
    },
    serverType: 'geoserver'
  })
});
var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [baselayer, layer1],
  controls: ol.control.defaults().extend([
    new ol.control.ScaleLine({
      units: 'metric'
    }),
    new ol.control.FullScreen()
  ]),
  target: 'mymap',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [2687148, 4556999],
    zoom: 6.5
  })
});
var element = document.getElementById('popup');
var popup = new ol.Overlay({
  element: element,
  positioning: 'bottom-center',
  stopEvent: false
});
map.addOverlay(popup);
map.on('click', function(evt) {
  var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function(feature, layer) {
    return feature;
  });
  if (feature) {
    var coord = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
    var props = feature.getProperties();
    var info = "<h2>bvnvb</h2>";
    // Offset the popup so it points at the middle of the marker not the tip
    popup.setOffset([0, -22]);
    popup.show(coord, info);
  } else {
    var url = layer1
      .getSource()
      .getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
        evt.coordinate,
        map.getView().getResolution(),
        map.getView().getProjection(), {
          'INFO_FORMAT': 'application/json',
          'propertyName': 'total_budget'
        }
      );
    reqwest({
      url: url,
      type: 'json',
    }).then(function(data) {
      var feature = data.features[0];
      var props = feature.properties;
      console.log(props.total_budget);
      var info = "<h2>" + props.total_budget + "</h2>";
      console.log(info);
      popup.show(evt.coordinate, info);
    });
  };
});
```

However, this always gives me an error of *Uncaught TypeError: popup.show is not a function*.
I added the ol-popup js and css files and still nothing. If anyone could help, I would be very thankful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found two issues based on your JsFiddle:

1. The element with id "popup" hasn't been defined in your HTML
2. There is no "show" method on `ol.Overlay`

You've mentioned OpenLayers 3 in your question, although your JsFiddle is using 4.6.5. I've tried the solution below with 4.6.5, it should work with 3 too.

1. Add the "popup" element

```html
<div id="popup"></div>
```

2. Replace your usage of `popup.show` with `popup.setPosition(ol.Coordinate)`, and update the content of your popup with `element.innerHTML`

```js
popup.setPosition(evt.coordinate);
element.innerHTML = info;
```

Here is an updated JsFiddle for example:
http://jsfiddle.net/swnykzgq/1/

Here are some Overlay examples from OpenLayers:
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/overlay.html

Comment: Thank you for your help. My bad about popup div, but your other note was the clue!